# hey,can someone help me to find out whats wrong with my code to solve Euler problem 50(Consecutive prime sum), its just work for below one-hundred

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following issue where my code successfully generates the first 100 primes but doesn't work afterwards. I'm not really sure what the issue is.

```py
a=0

def isprime(n):

    prime=True
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            prime=False
            break
    return prime

def irpb(x):

    javab=True
    for i in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
        if x%i==0:
            javab=False
            break
    return javab

for d in range(2,1*10**6):

    if isprime(d):
        #print("D is ",d)
        a+=d

if irpb(a):

    if a<1*10**6:
        print(a)

print("------Finish------")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Argon, welcome to SO! Could you please clarify what part of your code is causing problems and what those problems are? Thank you

Comment: Hi,thank you. its  work for primes below one-hundred,but idk why it not working for  below one-million & idk how debug this or find where i was wrong :/

Comment: @ArgonLinux try and edit your question to show that. It will wake it easier for people to help!

Comment: you may benefit from looking here how to asks good question with minimal and reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please put the error your get into your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error.
You want to print the sum of all the primes from 1 to N.  Fine.
For sure if "N" is 10^6 the sum of all the primes from 1 to N is higher than 10^6.
So your last condition:

```
if a<1*10**6:
    print(a)
```

when you put a range that is:

```
for d in range(2,1*10**6):
```

will never be true.

Here a solution:

```
a=0

N=10^6

def isprime(n):
    prime=True
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            prime=False
            break
    return prime


for d in range(2,N):
    if isprime(d):
        print("D is ",d)
        a+=d

if(N<=10^6)
  print(a)
```

Output:

```
37550402023
```